# Null exception trying to deploy or sign APK

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I did a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin.

I have a project that everything was working perfectly till I had formatted my windows and reinstalled everything.

The same project, but in a older version of the Visual Studio 2017 Community stills compile as usual.

And if I change the project to iOS, there is no option anymore to show IPA on the build server

I already reinstalled VS2017 Community

- When I do things with Android Project, he are set as a startup project
- When I do things with iOS Project, he are set as a startup project
- On both cases, if I set to debug or release, the menus on the images don't work.
- On both cases, on debug mode, if I hit CTRL+F5, it compiles and deploy on device and works perfect.
- On both cases, on debug mode, if I hit F5, it compiles, deploy and start the debugger.

So, what I can do to fix this? I need to release the apps...

[Screen 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgei.jpg)

[Screen 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEeYf.jpg)

[Screen 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/van2e.jpg)

Comment: So, you can run the applications in Debug and Release, but you just can't archive?

Comment: Can you check the Visual Studio logs? For more information

Comment: Based on your error message, You could deleted `Resource.designer.cs` file under `Resource` folder. Then deleted obj & bin folders in all solutions, closed the solution.then rebuild this solution.It is still not work, you could upload your logs.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Yes. I can run the app on the device (Android or iOS) but I cannot use the build APK. all the screens shows the exception.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Where I do find Visual Studio logs? I was trying to find it and didn't found any...

Comment: You can find it at the bottom of visual studio, click output

Comment: This log does not show anything..